# what is the difference between sharepoint app server and web server?

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2013

I'm new to sharepoint server. can anyone explain what is sharepoint webserver and app server.

Can i install sharepoint server and sql server in one machine and sharepoint solution (custom application) in another machine or all should be in same machine?

how to deploy/install the sharepoint 2013 application?

Answer (score 0):

> what is sharepoint webserver and app server

- The web server role delivers pages to end users (and web services, etc.).
- The app server role runs services like Excel Services and other services that can be offloaded from the web servers.

> Can i install sharepoint server and sql server in one machine

Yes, but for anything other than test, development or a very small production deployment. In a production environment you will want a redundant SQL install (clustering, mirroring, Always On, et.c). SQL and SharePoint will "fight" for resources on that one server.

> Sharepoint solution (custom application) in another machine or all should be in same machine?

Depends on the nature of the custom application. If it is a true Farm Level solution (WSP file), then that will probably need to be installed on the SharePoint web servers. If the app is a set of web services called from SharePoint web parts or pages, then it can be installed on another server. You will need to tell us more about your project.

> how to deploy/install the sharepoint 2013 application?

Are asking for how to install a SharePoint App or how to install SharePoint. For the app it will depend on the kind of app.

For installing SharePoint: Lots of resources at learn.microsoft.com and many web sites. Maybe start here for SharePoint 2013: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/install-for-sharepoint-2013

SharePoint 2013 is being phased out for support. You should be looking at SharePoint 2016 or later or SharePoint Online.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/product-servicing-policy/updated-product-servicing-policy-for-sharepoint-2013